# best practices loading knockout js models from server side code

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, knockout.js

I've inherited a site that uses knockout js and asp.net. The site runs decent after everything has been loaded but the initial load leaves a lot to be desired. Digging through the code there are around 20 models, each one calls an ajax method to get data from the server on page load. There is quite a bit of data being queried from the db which is causing the performance issue as the server sends the js, then the client sends and receives a large amount of data over 20 methods.

I want to handle all of the queries on server side before I send it to the client side, and then load the js models from that data. I am thinking about posting this data in a hidden div on the page as JSON and loading the models from there instead of an ajax call.

My question is, is this best practice? Is there a better way to optimize this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you inline the data from the 20 queries in the page response, then the page response time can be significantly prolonged. It will results in the browser having to sit and wait from the previous page or on a boring blank page.

However if you keep the solution as-is then the user will get the page initially much faster, and the data will pop-in when it is ready.

Although the total load time is probably going to be better with the data inlined, the perceived performance from the users perspective is going to be worse. Here is a nice post on the subject: http://www.lukew.com/ff/entry.asp?1797

Another benefit is that you don't have a weakest-link problem in that the page response time will be that of the slowest query. That will be quite severe in query timeout conditions.

Be also aware of issues if one query fails, then you must still inline the successful queries, and also handle the failed query.

I would argue that it is much better to do the queries from the browser.

There are some techniques to consider if you want to have the 20 queries executed more efficiently. Consider using something like SignalR to send all queries in a single connection and having the results also stream back in a single connection. I've used this technique previously with great success, it also enabled me to stream back cached results (from server-side cache) before the up-to-date results from a slow backend service was returned.

Comment: Do you have any links/examples of the SignalR stuff with Knockout?

Comment: Unfortunately nothing public to share no. I implemented the technique years ago before SignalR existing, then using a forever iframe. I sent a collection of queries in a normal XHR call which returned immediately without delay. The actual responses came in the forever frame (correlated id). This was at a time where some browsers had a restriction of only 2 concurrent XHR requests and we needed to do ~15. With SignalR it is much simpler to implement. This has nothing to do with knockout, however knockout makes it much simpler to update the UI from streaming data.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I will look into SignalR for SharePoint ECMAScript calls. The performance right now is very bad because the jquery has to wait until the calls are finished before it connects to any of the html controls on the page, giving the user 3 seconds of broken page time and just typing this out made me think I could try rearranging the order that the jquery executes on page load. Anyways, definitely answered my question. Thanks for the help!